# PHP : get file needs authentication

Tags: php, session, authentication, cookies

I'm trying to get a file by `file_get_contents()` from server , but the url needs authentication that is an ID , i dont know how may i integrate that id in my request .
  if i browse the url from my browser it redirects me to login page and wants me to enter the ID (15 digits id) , then i can download the file. 
I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329712/php-download-file-from-different-web-server-using-basic-authentication) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1336262/file-get-contents-behind-a-proxy) , but these solutions are for time we have a user&pass . how about my case that i have only one ID to get authenticated?

Comment: I don't get it, it sounds like you have an API key type idea that you want so the user would send your server this string by any means: `http://www.example.com/api/?apikey=123a123b123c123&file=123` and then you have logic that checks your database for a proper key, and if the key is good, you send the file `123 `. Is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: no . I'm talking about getting a file from server  A to server B that only authenticated users have access to. and the authentication form only has an ID field to be filled by user (this id says to server that this user is a valid user or not). if i want to do this process manually i will be redirected to login page and after filling the ID field and pressing login button , i can get the file. i want to do this process(authentication and then getting file) on a server . so now server A wants to download a file from server B that needs authentication . how may i do that?